# CodeIgniter query to see all post made by friend

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a project based on CodeIgniter and MySQL. I need suggestions in building CodeIgniter query.

What I want to achieve:

I have 3 tables, `profile`, `activity` and `friends`. The structure for these tables is:

**profile**

```
user_id | name
```

**activity**

```
activity_id | message | user_id | sharewith | createdtime
```

**friend**

```
 id | user1 | user2 | arefriends
```

Now I want to display all users' posts to everyone's / friends' walls according to who the user shares with. I have only two options for share with, either *share with everyone* or *share with only friends*.

For *share with everyone* I am storing `1` in the `sharewith` column of **activity** for the `user_id` and `2` for *share only with friends*.

I have built this query so far:

```
function load_activity()
{
    $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id'); 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('activity');
    $this->db->order_by("activity_id", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(15);
    $this->db->join('profile', 'profile.user_id = activity.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $data[]=$row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);              
}
```

How can I modify this query to display either all activities which are *shared with everyone* or *shared only with friends*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can, give some sample data for friend table. It's hard to tell the query with out the clear structure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only thing you need is a WHERE clause.
If the user isn't a friend they should only be able to see the 'share with everyone' activity.

```
function load_activity() {
    $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id'); 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('activity');
    $this->db->order_by("activity_id", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(15);
    $this->db->join('profile', 'profile.user_id = activity.user_id');
    if(!IS_FRIEND) {
        $this->db->where('sharewith', 1);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $data[]=$row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);              
}
```